# How do I get navigation menu on top with narrow viewport?

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I'm running Drupal 7.28 with Zen 7.x-5.5.  In the default setup, there is a region on the right side named "First sidebar" which contains a block named "Navigation".  I have put my navigation links there.  When shrinking the width of the browser to see how my site will be rendered on a mobile the navigation block gets positioned at the bottom of the page.

I want the navigation to be at the top in a mobile scenario, ideally with a bootstrap-esque collapsed menu.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Since I've used Bootstrap before and I feel it's more standard I've switched to using the [Bootstrap Base Theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

1. @media width queries in CSS
   http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/
   At a certain width, you could use a different positioning tactic, forcing it up top.
2. Via Javascript, checking against: window.innerWidth or body .clientWidth
   Many things you could do here, from changing CSS rules, to actually moving it in the DOM.
3. Using a Drupal module for responsive menus like:
   https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_navigation
   or https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_menus